# googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError when calling Admin SDK

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, http-status-code-500, google-directory-api

This is strange we have started receiving too many per day (nearly 300-500 times)

> googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError

while calling Admin SDK Directory API. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory

Google chat support for API is removed and Facing issue with how to address the problem. Our rate limit and query calls are way in the limits. We query Admin SDK as a cronjob schedule.

1. Is there a way we can debug 500 errors for AdminSDK
2. Is there any information regarding which deployment Region of Google is more capable to handle load?

[No error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFIHD.png)
[Logs error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daEji.png)

Comment: 500 errors are normally somethings wrong with the server, so you cant exactly debug that. 
 However if you include your code we could maybe help you get an idea whats wrong.   As for load handling don't run anything On the hour, everyone with a cron job has it scheduled fo ron the hour, your completing with them

Comment: We run them as cronjobs its a simple API call so Client side no changes. In logs we can clearly see 500 error however in the API console we see no errors. Strange and confused.

Comment: Added snaps from logs as well as console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Contact Workspace Support or File a Bug

As DalmTo pointed out, [500 errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) are usually out of your control. Especially in this case since you are calling Google's servers.

The best option to debug these errors is probably contacting support directly. You can find the corresponding contact information for your Workspace account ⁠on this page.

> https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en

If you are able to regularly reproduce this and you think its a bug, fill out the template here:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102

Ensure to include your code, complete reproduction steps, some evidence/statistics of the failures, and any other information you can give.

Comment: Raised a [BUG](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182297568)

Comment: Support team is also notified.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the Google Cloud Platform service account used for authentication was created *after* the in-app products.

To solve this, make a trivial edit to your in-app products in the Google Play Console. For example, add a temporary tag. Then try again to make the request and it should succeed.

By the way, the same is true for the [purchases.voidedpurchases](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.voidedpurchases/) which reports an "insufficient permissions" error.